# The member <some column> is not supported in SubSonic

Tags: .net, linq, subsonic, subsonic3

I am using the T4 templates of SubSonic 3.0 to generate classes and such for me. Well in my database I have a Zipcode table with these columns

- ZipCode_rid
- Zipcode (the actual zipcode in number format)
- State
- etc

Well, when the T4 templates run, instead of having a column like `Zipcode.Zipcode` I get `Zipcode.ZipcodeX`. Then, when trying to run a simple query across this table I get the cryptic error

> The member 'ZipcodeX' is not supported

The query is something simple like this

```
var z= from z in Zipcode.All()
       where (z.ZipcodeX == "12345")
       select z;
```

Is this a bug in SubSonic or am I messing something up? What workarounds are there?

I have temporarily worked around this issue by renaming the `Zipcode` column to `ZipCode`.. but this isn't a very good long term solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is both a bug in subsonic and you doing something wrong. Currently subsonic doesn't support columns with the same name as the table that contains them. The template tries to work around this by adding the X to the column name but the subsonic core then blows up.

The fix is to rename your column or table, Zipcode.Zipcode doesn't really make sense to me maybe Zipcode.Code would be more appropriate.

Comment: Not a very good answer, but it is the correct answer.. Regarding your own suggestion, we can't just rename it(other than make it different case) because we are currently in  a migration between using an ORM and appending strings to make our own queries..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but you can give it a try. It is a bit of a pain but I did get it to go.

**Step 1**
In settings.ttinclude there is a function

> string CleanUp(string tableName)

Create a new one just under it like this (adding whatever extension/rename algorithm you like

> string CleanUp(string colName, string tableName){
>
> ```
>   string result=colName;
>
>   //strip blanks
>   result=result.Replace(" ","");
>
>   //put your logic here...
>   if (result.ToLower() == tableName.ToLower())
>   {
>       result = colName + "X";
>   }
>
>   return result;
> ```
>
> }

**Step 2**
In SQLServer.ttinclude (or the equivalent file for your data source) there is at about line 167 a line like:

> col.CleanName = CleanUp(col.Name);

Change this to:

> col.CleanName = CleanUp(col.Name, tbl.Name);

**Step 3**
This is where the pain really starts. Grab the source code for SubSonic.Core (Yes :( ) and in DatabaseTable.cs change

> ```
>     public IColumn GetColumnByPropertyName(string PropertyName)
> ```

to

> ```
>     public virtual IColumn GetColumnByPropertyName(string PropertyName)
> ```

**Step 4**
In Structs.tt after

> public static string <#= col.CleanName #>Column{
>                   get{
>                     return "<#= col.Name #>";
>                 }
>             }

add the following

> <#          if (col.CleanName != col.Name) { #>
>
> ```
>        public override IColumn GetColumnByPropertyName(string columName){
>            if (columName == "<#= col.CleanName #>")
>                return <#=col.CleanName#>;
>             else
>                return base.GetColumnByPropertyName(columName);
>         }
> ```
>
> <#          } #>

You will probably need to regenerate all the .cs files after doing this.